# parse.com Does parse queries support other languages (such as chinese characters)

Tags: ios, mongodb, parse-platform

I am developing an ios-Application with parse.com, but it seems that the queries does not support *chinese characters*.

**For example:**

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "User")
query.whereKey("username", equalTo: "你好")
```

does not find any results even though the username is indeed in the database.

Is there a way to support query for different lanaguges? Or maybe use `query.whereKey(regexMatch)`?

Another workaround i can think of is write my own javascript cloud code to support chinese query.

Comment: ok heres what  i dont understand about stackoverflow, why are there downvotes to not obvious questions. There are no dupe answers found anywhere

Answer (score 0):

After playing with it I figured out the way is to use regex match:

query.whereKey("userName", matchesRegex: searchText, modifiers: "i")